# Will my email message be delivered when send with SMTP without internet connection?

Tags: c#, email, logging, smtp

My app send the logger via mail when the app crash but I have a doubt.
When I send a mail with SMTP without internet connection, the mail it sends after recover the connection or the code throw a exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your sending method.

If you specify the `SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory` or `SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis` method, you can enqueue an email message before it actually sends. The IIS server's SMTP server will pick it up when there is a connection. ([Read more on the SMTP service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480390.aspx))

For the remaining `SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network` method (which sends the email directly), you will receive an exception when there is no internet connection.

Comment: I try with SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis but when I test it throw this exception "IIS delivery is not supported".
I don't know if is for Unity or cause the app/game is for iOS

Comment: That will obviously only work running from IIS. There is no IIS drop location when running in an iOS app...